# Conversion und comparison between Long and Double in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm playing around with Scala `AnyVal` Types and having trouble to unterstand the following: I convert `Long.MaxValue` to `Double` and back to `Long`. As `Long` (64bit) can hold more digits than `Double`'s mantissa (52 bits), I expected that this conversion will make some data be lost, but somehow this is not the case:

```
Long.MaxValue.equals(Long.MaxValue.toDouble.toLong) // is true
```

I thought there is maybe some magic/optimisation in `Long.MaxValue.toDouble.toLong` such that the conversion is not really happening. So I also tried:

```
Long.MaxValue.equals("9.223372036854776E18".toDouble.toLong) // is true
```

If I evaluate the expression `"9.223372036854776E18".toDouble.toLong`, this gives:

```
9223372036854775807
```

This really freaks me out, the last 4 digits seem just to pop up from nowhere!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: as usual with questions like this, there is nothing special about Scala, all modern languages (that I know of) use IEEE 754 floating point (at least in practice, if the language specification doesn't require it) and will behave the same, just with different type and operation names.

Yes, data is lost. If you try e.g. `(Long.MaxValue - 1).toDouble.toLong`, you'll still get `Long.MaxValue` back. You can find the next smallest `Long` you can get from `someDouble.toLong` as follows:

```
scala> Math.nextDown(Long.MaxValue.toDouble).toLong
res0: Long = 9223372036854774784
```

> If I evaluate the expression `"9.223372036854776E18".toDouble.toLong`, this gives:
>
> ```
> 9223372036854775808
> ```
>
> This really freaks me out, the last 4 digits seem just to pop up from nowhere!

You presumably mean `9223372036854775807`. `9.223372036854776E18` is of course actually larger than that: it represents `9223372036854776000`. But you'll get the same result if you use any other `Double` larger than `Long.MaxValue` as well, e.g. `1E30.toLong`.

Comment: Thanks, I somhow did not see that 9.223372036854776E18 is larger than Long.MaxValue. In this case of course I will always Long.MaxValue back. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

Just remark, Double and Long values in Scala are equivalent of primitive types double and long.

The result of `Long.MaxValue.toDouble` is in reality bigger then `Long.MaxValue`, the reason is, that value is rounded. Next conversion i.e. `Long.MaxValue.toDouble.toLong` is "rounded" back to the value of `Long.MaxValue`.